# Simplifying q-series expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, q-series

Hi I am wondering if there is a general procedure (perhaps for a specific class) simplifying q-series of the form $(q^a;q^{na})_{\infty}$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, into the product/qoutient of q-series which are of the form $(q^b;q^b)_{\infty}$ . I know that $(q^2;q^4)_{\infty} = \frac{ (q^2;q^2)_{\infty}}{(q^4;q^4)_{\infty} }.$

I have several q-series like $(q^2;q^6)_{\infty}$ and $(q^{10};q^2)_{\infty}$, to name a few, which I need to simplify.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are out of luck. Yes, $(q^n;q^{2n})_\infty = (q^n;q^n)_\infty/(q^{2n},q^{2n})_\infty$ but otherwise there is **no** other such finite product/quotient. You might be interested in my "Dedekind eta-function identities" file.